# Interleave between normal python methods and generators during generator execution

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, generator, concurrent.futures

Is it possible to interleave from a generator execution to normal method execution using `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`.

```
import concurrent.futures
from app import executor


def generator():
    for val in external_api():
        yield val


def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2


def stream():
    generator_future = executor.submit(generator)
    future1 = executor.submit(func1)
    future2 = executor.submit(func2)

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed([generator_future, future1, future2]):
        if future == generator_future:
            generator_result = future.result()
            for value in generator_result:
                yield value
        else:
            yield future.result()
```

If generator execution is started, normal method results cannot be yielded in `stream()`, even when `func1` or `func2` is completed. Normal method results are on hold until generator yielding is done. Is it possible to yield `func1` and `func2` results during generator yielding.

Note: Using above snippet within flask application with [Flask-Executor](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Executor/) wrapper for `ThreadPoolExecutor` to push application context to threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having some difficulty in understanding what your problem is or possibly you do not understand what is taking place. We shall find out together:

When you call a generator function, and I don't care how complicated it is inside or how long it takes to yield all its values, it returns almost instantaneously with an iterator **that when iterated executes the code within the generator function to get all the elements generated with the `yield` statement.** The following demonstrates that what the multithreading pool is returning is an `Iterator` (also an `Iterable`), but you should know that since you *are* iterating this result:

```py
import concurrent.futures
from collections.abc import Iterator

def generator():
    import time

    # Simulate an api call:
    time.sleep(.5)

    for val in range(3, 9):
        yield val


def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2


def stream():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3)
    generator_future = executor.submit(generator)
    future1 = executor.submit(func1)
    future2 = executor.submit(func2)

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed([generator_future, future1, future2]):
        if future == generator_future:
            generator_result = future.result()
            # Demonstrate that what is returned from calling
            # generator() is an iterator:
            print(isinstance(generator_result, Iterator))
            for value in generator_result:
                yield value
        else:
            yield future.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(stream()))
```

Prints:

```None
True
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2]
```

So of the three submitted tasks, which are all relatively trivial, the first one submitted completes first and this one is the call to the generator function. But you then immediately start iterating this iterator and this results in calling your (probably non-trivial) external api that returns multiple values that will be "yielded". You will not be checking the completion for any of the other two submitted tasks to the pool until you have retrieved all the yielded values and this will hold up getting any other results.

**Why are you using a generator function?** This means that the actual call to the external api will be performed by your main thread and not in one of the pool threads. To overlap the api call with other task submissions, try:

```py
import concurrent.futures
from collections.abc import Iterable

def call_external_api():
    import time

    # Simulate an api call:
    time.sleep(.5)

    # Results from the call to the api:
    return [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2


def stream():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3)
    futures = [
        executor.submit(call_external_api),
        executor.submit(func1),
        executor.submit(func2)
    ]

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        if isinstance(result, Iterable):
            for elem in result:
                yield elem
        else:
           yield result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(stream()))
```

Prints:

```None
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**A Second Way**

If you are forced to use function `generator` as is (i.e. a generator function), then make sure that the iteration of it is done by the thread pool as follows:

```py
import concurrent.futures
from collections.abc import Iterable

def generator():
    import time

    # Simulate an api call:
    time.sleep(.5)

    for val in range(3, 9):
        yield val

def iterate_generator(generator):
    return list(generator)

def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2


def stream():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3)
    futures = [
        executor.submit(iterate_generator, generator()),
        executor.submit(func1),
        executor.submit(func2)
    ]

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        if isinstance(result, Iterable):
            for elem in result:
                yield elem
        else:
           yield result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(stream()))
```

**Summary**

It makes no sense to pass a generator function as the argument to `concurrent.futures.submit` since the real work is not done by calling the generator but rather in iterating the results of that call.

**Update: Solution Using Threads**

```py
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from random import random
from time import sleep

class Sentinel:
    pass

# Represents "this thread is done generating results":
sentinel = Sentinel()

def generator():
    # Simulate an api call:
    sleep(random() / 8.0)

    for val in range(3, 9):
        # Some randomness so that tasks do not always
        # complete at the same time:
        sleep(random() / 5.0)
        yield val

def iterate_generator(output_queue):
    for result in generator():
        output_queue.put(result)
    # Show we are not returning any more results:
    output_queue.put(sentinel)

def func1(output_queue):
    # Some randomness so that tasks do not always
    # complete at the same time:
    sleep(random() / 4.0)
    output_queue.put(1)
    # Show we are not returning any more results:
    output_queue.put(sentinel)

def func2(output_queue):
    # Some randomness so that tasks do not always
    # complete at the same time:
    sleep(random() / 5.0)
    output_queue.put(2)
    # Show we are not returning any more results:
    output_queue.put(sentinel)

def stream():
    output_queue = Queue()

    threads = [
        Thread(target=iterate_generator, args=(output_queue,)),
        Thread(target=func1, args=(output_queue,)),
        Thread(target=func2, args=(output_queue,))
    ]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    n_threads = len(threads)
    # Retrieve results until we have seen n_threads
    # sentinel values. Then we know all tasks have finished:
    while n_threads:
        result = output_queue.get()
        if result is sentinel:
            n_threads -= 1
        else:
            yield result

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Perform multiple runs:
    for _ in range(10):
        print(list(stream()))
```

Output from successive runs:

```None
[2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Apologies, Second way answers my requirement, but one issue would be, we start yielding values in `stream()` only after the generator yielding is completed. But I want to yield values from `generator()` in `stream()` as and when `generator()` yields but also concurrently process `func1()` and `func2()` and yield values from `func1()` and `func2()` in `stream()` as soon as it completes even while `generator()` is yielding.

Comment: `stream()` is a streaming API consumed in frontend. `generator()`, `func1()`,  `func2()` provides values to be yielded. All 3 are bit I/O intensive tasks.

Comment: In terms output from code snippet, never in our code is a output like `[3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 8]` is possible, as we yield `generator()` values only after whole iteration of `generator()`completes . `3, 4, ,5, 6, 7, 8` sticks together. It'd be great if its possible yield values from `func1()`, `func2()` while `generator()` is yielding.

Comment: In short, it'd be great to yield, iterating generator values in concurrence with (`func1()`, `func2()`), while iterating

Comment: What you want cannot be done with either `concurrent.futures` or `multiprocessing` modules. It *can* be done if you use explicit `Thread` and `Queue` instances. See update to answer.